# Como criar arquivos em lotes com variável

Tags: batch

Olá, não entendo nada sobre programação. Descobri como criar scripts .bat e estou utilizando para facilitar minha vida. Diariamente eu tenho que abrir várias páginas da internet no meu trabalho, então criei um arquivo .bat usando o comando START para abrir todas as páginas de que eu preciso de uma só vez. Está funcionando. Acontece que duas dessas páginas eu preciso abrir só nas sextas-feiras. Eu preciso criar um script com uma lista de 8 páginas, mas para duas delas eu quero que ele cheque se o dia atual é sexta-feira e só abra a página se for sexta-feira, do contrário ele abrirá somente as outras páginas que não têm essa condição. Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta e acrescente o código que você já tem hoje.

Comment: você quer saber fazer a variavel ou usar o valor da variavel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara batch é muito antigo, não tem muitos recursos. Então recomendo você ver o PowerShell, você vai poder automatizar muita coisa com isso. Inclusive tô usando o PowerShell para pegar o dia da semana:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell "[Int] (Get-Date).DayOfWeek"') DO set dia=%%i
```

Do que você precisa é de um comando condicional `IF`, que só vai executar um bloco de comandos se uma condição for verdadeira:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell "[Int] (Get-Date).DayOfWeek"') DO set dia=%%i

IF %dia%==5 (
    ECHO Hoje e Sexta!
    ECHO Abrir mais duas paginas...
)

ECHO Tudo o que preciso todos os dias!
```

Você também pode usar o `IF-ELSE` que vai executar o que tiver dentro do `ELSE` se a condição for falsa:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('powershell "[Int] (Get-Date).DayOfWeek"') DO set dia=%%i

IF %dia%==5 (
    ECHO Hoje e Sexta!
    ECHO Abrir mais duas paginas...
) ELSE (
    ECHO Hoje nao e Sexta!
    ECHO Caso que queira abrir alguma coisa...
)

ECHO Tudo o que preciso todos os dias!
```

E como hoje é sexta, a saída:

[image: saída]

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado pela colaboração!

Answer (score 0):

A mesma solução com o PowerShell:

Primeiro você vai executar o PowerShell como administrador e entrar o comando

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Isso vai permitir que você execute os scripts no seu computador.

Depois você vai abrir o *Windows PowerShell ISE*, que um editor que vem no windows para scripts:

E o código é:

```
$dia = [Int] (Get-Date).DayOfWeek
if ($dia -eq 5) {
    Start "https://www.google.com/search?q=happy%20hour%20promoção"
} else {
    Start "https://jornaldoempreendedor.com.br/destaques/10-dicas-para-relaxar-seu-cerebro-enquanto-trabalha/"
}
Start "http://fazenda.gov.br"
```

[image: psise]

Setinha verde executa para testar, salva em um lugar e para executar é só usar o botão direito e mantar executar como PowerShell

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]